# Specified template parameter on a constructor

Tags: c++

Here is my code:

```
class test{
    public:
    template<int B>
    test(const char(&a)[B]){
        std::cout<<B<<std::endl;
    }
};
int main(int argc, char** argv) {


    test t("test");
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
5
```

I was doing some researching and came upon this code. It will count the number of characters(-1 for the exact). I am wondering about the purpose of a specified `int B`. inside the template parameter, is it gonna work if i have something like:

```
class test{
public:
template<char B> 
test(){

}
};
int main(int argc, char** argv) {


    test t(); //error, how to make it work?

    return 0;
}
```

My questions are:

From my first example, how did it exactly count the number of characters? what's the purpose of specifying the type inside a the template constructor, like from my example number 2, how do i make it work if i have a char type? ( i get an error when i try to compile )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first example, `"test"` can be thought of as `const char s[5] = "test"`. From there the template can be constructed as `const char(&a)[5]`, but since `B` is used in to template definition, the "5" is grabbed as `B`s value.

You're second example / question isn't clear.

Comment: Ahhh i mean, how to grab off something if it's a character. I don't know how to implement it so i have no clear example.

Comment: If you want any "random" value (a value that has no special meaning, which you didn't provide in your example BTW) just pass it in as an input variable.

Comment: hmm alright, i somehow get the essence. So normally if it has no default value such as `int B = 0`, it's meant to grab something.

Answer (score 0):

String literals in C++ have types of constant character arrays. So string literal `"test"` has type `const char[5]` (string literals include the terminating zero).
Thus in the first program the compiler can determine template argument because the array (string literal) is passed by reference.

In the second program this declaration

```
test t();
```

is a declaration of a function that has return type `test` and does not have parameters.

If you want to declare an object of class test in the second program you could write the program for example the following way

```
class test{
public:
template<char B = 'A'> 
test(){

}
};
int main(int argc, char** argv) {


    test t;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Amit According to the C++ Standard such constructions are considered as function declarations and not as a class object definition.

Comment: @kiviak First of all remove your down vote and secondly the code is correct and you can check it using for example the on-line compilers. at www.ideone.com

Comment: i check it using vs2010,so you can try

Comment: @kiviak VS2010 is a compiler that does not support all features of the C++ 2011 Standard including default template arguments of function template parameters. As I already said try the code at www.ideone.com selecting C++11. or C++14